# How to Authenticate User with password for Azure Active Directory from a desktop client without registering client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-active-directory

While connecting to Azure Active Directory(Azure AD) from a native desktop application we need to register this application as client application in portal. Can we connect it without registering client application?

Answer (score 3):

No , you have to register an app to use.It's not possible to acquire token without registering an application .

Any application that wants to use the capabilities of Azure AD must first be registered in an Azure AD tenant. This registration process involves giving Azure AD details about your application, such as the URL where it’s located, the URL to send replies after a user is authenticated, the URI that identifies the app, and so on.